# Node.js execFile(): Is passing password as argument secure?

Tags: node.js, linux, security

Is it safe to pass a password as user input to the [`execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback) command?

Example:

```js
const process = await execFile(
  'somecommand',
  ['--password', passwordFromUser, '--username', userName],
);
```

I am aware this does not use a shell (`sh`) to execute the command, rather it uses [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) under the hood. But can the supplied password be seen in some kind of history table or anything similar? What I want to avoid is that someone else can still see that password in Linux somehow.

Is it safer to pass the password via the `options.env` object when possible?